# Query with FK=PK condition but showing rows without FK too

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need help writting a query that has a condition like this in the WHERE clause

```
Select a.field, b.field
From Table1 a, Table2 b
Where a.FK = b.PK
```

But I also want the select to return rows that has no FK reference in the field a.FK, in this case the b.field should return some empty or null value.

Thanks

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `Left Outer JOIN`. Try the following:

```
SELECT a.field, b.field
FROM Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b
ON a.FK = b.PK
```

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) is a good read how `LEFT JOIN` works

Answer (score 1):

Use `Left Join`. This should give you what you are looking for.

```
Select a.field, b.field
From Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b on a.FK = b.PK
```